# How to create SwiftUI TextField that accepts only numbers and a single dot?

Tags: ios, textfield, swiftui

How to create a swiftui textfield that allows the user to only input numbers and a single dot?
In other words, it checks digit by digit as the user inputs, if the input is a number or a dot and the textfield doesn't have another dot the digit is accepted, otherwise the digit entry is ignored.
Using a stepper isn't an option.

Comment: You can perhaps do it with a formatter although I haven't had much success with them. The method I use is to create an ObservableObject with a string, test the values in didSet and update if they don't fit your pattern.

Comment: Edited my answer with further details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SwiftUI doesn't let you specify a set of allowed characters for a `TextField`. Actually, it's not something related to the UI itself, but to how you manage the model behind. In this case the model is the text behind the `TextField`. So, you need to change your view model.

If you use the `$` sign on a `@Published` property you can get access to the `Publisher` behind the `@Published` property itself. Then you can attach your own subscriber to the publisher and perform any check you want. In this case I used the `sink` function to attach a closure based subscriber to the publisher:

```
/// Attaches a subscriber with closure-based behavior.
///
/// This method creates the subscriber and immediately requests an unlimited number of values, prior to returning the subscriber.
/// - parameter receiveValue: The closure to execute on receipt of a value.
/// - Returns: A cancellable instance; used when you end assignment of the received value. Deallocation of the result will tear down the subscription stream.
public func sink(receiveValue: @escaping ((Self.Output) -> Void)) -> AnyCancellable
```

The implementation:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
    private var subCancellable: AnyCancellable!
    private var validCharSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890.")

    init() {
        subCancellable = $text.sink { val in
            //check if the new string contains any invalid characters
            if val.rangeOfCharacter(from: self.validCharSet.inverted) != nil {
                //clean the string (do this on the main thread to avoid overlapping with the current ContentView update cycle)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.text = String(self.text.unicodeScalars.filter {
                        self.validCharSet.contains($0)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        subCancellable.cancel()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Type something...", text: $viewModel.text)
    }
}
```

Important to note that:

- `$text` (`$` sign on a `@Published` property) gives us an object of type `Published<String>.Publisher` i.e. a publisher
- `$viewModel.text` (`$` sign on an `@ObservableObject`) gives us an object of type `Binding<String>`

That are two completely different things.

**EDIT**: If you want you can even create you own custom `TextField` with this behaviour. Let's say you want to create a `DecimalTextField` view:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct DecimalTextField: View {
    private class DecimalTextFieldViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var text = ""
        private var subCancellable: AnyCancellable!
        private var validCharSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890.")

        init() {
            subCancellable = $text.sink { val in                
                //check if the new string contains any invalid characters
                if val.rangeOfCharacter(from: self.validCharSet.inverted) != nil {
                    //clean the string (do this on the main thread to avoid overlapping with the current ContentView update cycle)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.text = String(self.text.unicodeScalars.filter {
                            self.validCharSet.contains($0)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        deinit {
            subCancellable.cancel()
        }
    }

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = DecimalTextFieldViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Type something...", text: $viewModel.text)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        DecimalTextField()
    }
}
```

This way you can use your custom text field just writing:

```
DecimalTextField()
```

and you can use it wherever you want.

Comment: How to use in an existing app? i.e. DecimalTextField($myValue) ?

Comment: @caram I made a [working example of that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59621625/numberfield-or-how-to-make-textfield-input-a-double-float-or-other-numbers-with). its not perfect and can be improved, but better then nothing. There I using it like this:
    `DecimalTextField("123", numericValue: $numeric)`

Comment: Thanks so much for providing this very helpful answer, which taught me a lot about Combine and the SwiftUI use of pub/sub.  I believe this approach can be simplified to remove explicit subscriptions and the resulting threading issues.  See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/brotskydotcom/a5a41eec5419aaaef5e3aceb75e1921c) for a working example including usage examples.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple solution for TextField validation: (updated)

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var text = ""

func validate() -> Binding<String> {
    let acceptableNumbers: String = "0987654321."
    return Binding<String>(
        get: {
            return self.text
    }) {
        if CharacterSet(charactersIn: acceptableNumbers).isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: $0)) {
            print("Valid String")
            self.text = $0
        } else {
            print("Invalid String")
            self.text = $0
            self.text = ""
        }
    }
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        TextField("Text", text: validate())
            .padding(24)
        Spacer()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using an async dispatch is the wrong approach and may cause other issues. Here's an implementation that achieves the same thing with a `Double`-backed property and manually iterates over the characters each time you type in the bound view.

```
final class ObservableNumber: ObservableObject {

    let precision: Int

    @Published
    var value: String {
        didSet {
            var decimalHit = false
            var remainingPrecision = precision
            let filtered = value.reduce(into: "") { result, character in

                // If the character is a number that by adding wouldn't exceed the precision and precision is set then add the character.
                if character.isNumber, remainingPrecision > 0 || precision <= 0 {
                    result.append(character)

                    // If a decimal has been hit then decrement the remaining precision to fulfill
                    if decimalHit {
                        remainingPrecision -= 1
                    }

                // If the character is a decimal, one hasn't been added already, and precision greater than zero then add the decimal.
                } else if character == ".", !result.contains("."), precision > 0 {
                    result.append(character)
                    decimalHit = true
                }
            }

            // Only update value if after processing it is a different value.
            // It will hit an infinite loop without this check since the published event occurs as a `willSet`.
            if value != filtered {
                value = filtered
            }
        }
    }

    var doubleValue: AnyPublisher<Double, Never> {
        return $value
            .map { Double($0) ?? 0 }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    init(precision: Int, value: Double) {
        self.precision = precision
        self.value = String(format: "%.\(precision)f", value)
    }
}
```

This solution also ensures you only have a single decimal instead of allowing multiple instances of `"."`.

Note the extra computed property to put it "back" into a `Double`. This allows you to continue to react to the number as a number instead of a `String` and have to cast/convert everywhere. You could very easily add as many computed properties as you want to react to it as `Int` or whatever numeric type as long as you convert it in the way you would expect.

*One more note* you could also make it generic `ObservableNumber<N: Numeric>` and handle different inputs but using `Double` and keeping the generics out of it will simplify other things down the road. Change according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution is to set .numberPad keyboardType:

```
  TextField(
     "0.0", 
     text: $fromValue
  )
  .keyboardType(UIKeyboardType.numberPad)
```