# SwiftUI TextField does not accept integers/double. How to do so?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm starting off with iOS App Development and SwiftUI is my first step.

I'm unable to input an integer or a double value from the user.

```
@State public var num1: Double = 0
TextField(" Enter a Number", text: $num1)
//Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Double>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'
```

Please Help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Binding<Int> with a TextField SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59507471/use-bindingint-with-a-textfield-swiftui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftUI’s components expect to have two-way bindings to properties, using something like @State, Have you used **@State** before declaring the num1 property ?

you can do something like this :

Declare the variable num1 as

```
@State private var num1 = ""
```

You TextField cant directly take Integer or Double input, you have to take only String input and can Typecast the required value during evaluation, as

```
print("Input taken is : \(Double(num1))")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I have already applied the State var in my code. The error has been persistent.

Comment: See Praduyt ... Make num1 type String, then try to compile

Comment: Yeah of course that works as it only accepts String values. My purpose for using Double is to conduct arithmetic operations which cannot be achieved by String variable.

Comment: Have you tried formatter Argument for TextField, you have to pass a DoubleFormatter() as A formatter Parameter for TextField !

Comment: I had also tried the formatter argument, the error says "Extra argument 'formatter' in call".
I just tried with DoubleFormatter() and nothing as such is present.

Answer (score 1):

Actually they can accept numbers. Just try a different initializer for `TextField`

`TextField("placeholder", value: $yourValue, formatter: NumberFormatter())`