# How to make Swift Coordinator reflect parent's bindings changes?

Tags: swift, swiftui, appkit, combine

Let's say I have:

- structure `Document`, which represents text document.
- `EditorView`  — an `NSTextView`, wrapped with Combine, which binds to `Document.content<String>`.

`Document` is a part of complex `store:ObservableObject`, so it can be bouneded to `EditorView` instance.

When I first create binding, it works as expected — editing NSTextView changes value in `Document.content`.

```swift
let document1 = Document(...)
let document2 = Document(...)
var editor = EditorView(doc: document1)
```

But if change binding to another Document...

```swift
editor.doc = document2
```

...then `updateNSView` can see new `document2`. But inside Coordiantor's `textDidChange`  has still refrence to `document1`.

```swift
func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let textView = notification.object as? NSTextView else {
        return
    }

    self.parent.doc.content = textView.string
    self.selectedRanges = textView.selectedRanges
}
```

So, initially, when i set new bindint, NSTextView changes it content to `document2`, but as I type, coordinator sends changes to `document1`.

Is it true, that Coordiantor keeps it's own copy of `parent`, and even if parent changes (`@Binding doc` is updated), it still references to old one?

How to make Coordinator reflect parent's bindings changes?

Thank you!

```swift
struct Document: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var content: String
}

struct EditorView: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var doc: Document

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> CustomTextView {
        let textView = CustomTextView(
            text: doc.content,
            isEditable: isEditable,
            font: font
        )
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator

        return textView
    }

    func updateNSView(_ view: CustomTextView, context: Context) {
        view.text = doc.content
        view.selectedRanges = context.coordinator.selectedRanges

    }
}


// MARK: - Coordinator

extension EditorView {

    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSTextViewDelegate {
        var parent: EditorView
        var selectedRanges: [NSValue] = []

        init(_ parent: EditorView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func textDidBeginEditing(_ notification: Notification) {
            guard let textView = notification.object as? NSTextView else {
                return
            }

            self.parent.doc.content = textView.string
            self.parent.onEditingChanged()
        }

        func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
            guard let textView = notification.object as? NSTextView else {
                return
            }

            self.parent.doc.content = textView.string
            self.selectedRanges = textView.selectedRanges
        }

        func textDidEndEditing(_ notification: Notification) {
            guard let textView = notification.object as? NSTextView else {
                return
            }

            self.parent.doc.content = textView.string
            self.parent.onCommit()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - CustomTextView

final class CustomTextView: NSView {
    private var isEditable: Bool
    private var font: NSFont?

    weak var delegate: NSTextViewDelegate?

    var text: String {
        didSet {
            textView.string = text
        }
    }
    // ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it true, that Coordiantor keeps it's own copy of parent, and even
>   if parent changes (@Binding doc is updated), it still references to
>   old one?

A parent, ie `EditorView` here, is struct, so answer is yes, in general it can be copied.

> How to make Coordinator reflect parent's bindings changes?

Instead of (or additional to) parent, inject binding to Coordinator (via constructor) explicitly and work with it directly.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not quite sure, how to do it property: new to Swift. Could you please take a look, how propetly assign data to bound value? Swift tells me binding is immutable structure, so it's value can't be assigned directly.

Comment: @f1nn, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59509242/12299030) for example of passing binding to coordinator and work with it.

Comment: @Asperi - I find this is not working - I have the same issue and am using the same approach as 'this answer' above.  However the binding change is not reflected and the edits in the text field are still being sent to the original object.  I have a master detail arrangement and any edits are always sent to the first document that is selected since the Coordinator appears to never change the binding when a new document is selected from the list.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald, see example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63761738/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi - thanks but say what !! why are you building the whole stack from scratch in that example ?  Is there some issue with using the approach above ?

Comment: Asperi - on closer inspection I can see it is working for plain text strings but it is not working when using an Attributed String