# Capturing all selection change events for an NSTextView, including those caused by mouse drags

Tags: swift, swiftui, nstextview

I have a `NSViewRepresentable` that contains an `NSScrollView` with a `NSTextView` inside.

```
struct MultilineTextField: NSViewRepresentable {
    typealias NSViewType = NSScrollView
    private let scrollView = NSScrollView()
    private let textView = NSTextView()
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var loc: NSRange
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSScrollView {
        textView.string = text
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        scrollView.documentView = textView
        return scrollView
    }
    func updateNSView(_ scrollView: NSScrollView, context: Context) {}
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSTextViewDelegate {
        let textField: MultilineTextField
        init(_ textField: MultilineTextField) {
            self.textField = textField
        }
        func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
            textField.text = textField.textView.string
        }
        func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ notification: Notification) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.textField.loc = self.textField.textView.selectedRange()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to extract the `selectedRange` of the `NSTextView` to be displayed in a different view, eg:

```
Text(String(loc.location))
```

It works when the `selectedRange` is changed with arrow keys and on mouse down and mouse up, but it seems like `textViewDidChangeSelection` doesn't get called when in the  middle of dragging the mouse over the text. As a result, the displayed `loc.location` value doesn't change while dragging until the mouse is lifted up.

As a workaround, I've tried subclassing `NSTextView` to override the [`mouseMoved`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1525114-mousemoved) method, but it seems like that doesn't get called either for some reason.

Just to verify that `selectedRange` actually gets updated on mouse drag, I tried continually updating `loc` (this is in the `Coordinator` class):

```
init(_ textField: MultilineTextField) {
    self.textField = textField
    super.init()
    updateSelection()
}
func updateSelection() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.textField.loc = self.textField.textView.selectedRange()
        self.updateSelection()
    }
}
```

This code does work, but also uses 100% CPU for no reason.

Is there a way to be notified when `selectedRange` changes in the case of mouse dragging?

Comment: @Asperi It would change when dragging backwards, but either way `loc.length` doesn't change either.

Comment: As far as I see the representable is designed incorrectly - NS* properties will be recreated every time view is updated. See next for working approach, which you can extend for your needs https://stackoverflow.com/a/63761738/12299030.