# SwiftUI custom number formatter as phone

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, formatter

I'm trying to create a custom phone formatter. I found [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit) that could work for my particular case, the problem with this is that when I tried it there are multiple issues like:

- If using `.international` the program enters in a loop and becomes irresponsive
- It requires the number to contain the country's phone-code inside the text to be able to format it correctly, but as I have already done this part in a Button with a flag + phone code on the left, it's not necessary.

So, what I'm trying to do is to create my own PhoneFormatter, something like: `(###) ###-####`, currently this might suffice as we're only targeting a single country and this is the most common format used here.

I'm following the code from [this site](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-format-text-inside-text-views) to get an idea of how to do it, but here they are working with dates:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    static let taskDateFormat: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .long
        return formatter
    }()

    var dueDate = Date()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Task due date: \(dueDate, formatter: Self.taskDateFormat)")
    }
}
```

Someone asked something similar 2 years ago on [Apple's Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/88808) but I believe it was for UIKit rather than SwiftUI and there's no code shown there.

I'm trying to attach my formatter directly to my own `TextField`, I've tried looking for something similar with SwiftUI and I haven't found anything, and still can't find myself how to create my own custom formatter using something like `formatter.numberStyle = "(###) ###-####"`

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Consider this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/59509242/12299030

Comment: @Asperi I must admit this approach might be what I want, it blows my mind as I'm not that experienced with SwiftUI. As far as I understand, this is a SwiftUI View that is wrapping an UITextField but it confuses me on how you make it to add those commas. WOW

Comment: @Asperi would you consider explaining a little bit with comments on your linked answer how you make those changes please? Or a little tip on how could I build over it to my specific use case?