# How to build NumberField in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm working on **MacOS** and I try to make `NumberField` — something like TextField, but for numbers. In rather big tree of views at the top I had:

```
 ...
 VStack {
      ForEach(instances.indices, id:\.self) {index in
         TextField("",
            text: Binding( 
                get: {"\(String(format: "%.1f", instances[index].values[valueIndex]))"},
                set: {setValueForInstance(index, valueIndex, $0)})
             )                   
       }
 }
 ...
```

And it worked well, but not nice:

- ✔︎ when I changed value, all View structure was redrawn – good
- ✔︎ values was updated if they were changed by another part of Views structure – good
- ✖︎ it was updated after each keypresses, which was annoying, when I tried to input `1.2`, just after pressing `1` view was updated to `1.0`. Possible to input every number but inconvenient – bad

So, I tried to build `NumberField`.

```
    var format = "%.1f"
    struct NumberField : View {
        @Binding var number: Double {
            didSet {
                stringNumber = String(format: format, number)
            }
        }
        @State var stringNumber: String
        var body: some View {
            TextField("" , text: $stringNumber, onCommit: {
                print ("Commiting")
                if let v = Double(stringNumber) {
                    number = v
                } else {
                    stringNumber = String(format:format, number)
                }
                print ("\(stringNumber) , \(number)" )
            })
        }
        init (number: Binding<Double>) {
            self._number = number
            self._stringNumber = State(wrappedValue: String(format:format, number.wrappedValue))
        }
    }
```

And It's called from the same place as before:

```
 ...
 VStack {
      ForEach(instances.indices, id:\.self) {index in
         NumberField($instances[index].values[valueIndex])                  
       }
 }
 ...
```

But in this case it never updates `NumberField View` if values was changed by another part of View. Whats's wrong? Where is a trick?

Comment: The following should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59509242/12299030.