# swiftUI handle keyboard input (popup and intercept text insertion)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swiftui, keyboard-events

I trying to make some interaction. The idea is to show user a letter (it's not a `TextField` - with no cursor). When he taps a letter, the keyboard pops up. User taps a key on keyboard, I receive text insertion, if its correct - I will show next letter. If user taps anywhere outside the letter frame - keyboard must hide. If he taps letter again - keyboard must pop up again.

so, I find 2 solution to hide keyboard:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.endEditing(force)
```

and

```
UIApplication.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
```

The second one is more intresting, I think. It looks like I can send a `View` to subscribe it to keyboard input, and it will make a Keyboard to pop up, right? So the question is, **can I make some custom `SwiftUI View` to be responder, and how do I make it to handle user text input.**

p.s. I don't have any experience with `UIKit`, so I'd appreciate some links if there is an answer.

p.p.s. There is a way to use `TextField` and to bind `ObservebleObject` text property like it was shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59637971/12616648) but is there a way to make custom view with keyboard interact ability without using TextField?

> ```
>  @Published var text = ""{
>         didSet{
>              //do some check here
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and unfortunately you didn't even try to code something. You should post your (in best case copyable/runnable) code here...and normally you should just ask one question. Yes, you can do it, just implement onTapGesture on the whole view to hide the keyboard and onTapGesture on your whatever view to show the keyboard.

Comment: @Chris, all I can do right now is to show keyboard on start with             `uiView.becomeFirstResponder()`. But I had to do `UIKit` for that purpose and put it in  `UIViewRepresentable` struct. Even though I can't bring it back after dissmissing. So the question is: Is there a native `SwiftUI` way of making some custom logic with keyboard interaction?